# Is it possible to split an entity into two tables using NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

Here's the situation.  I have a table called Users and a table called Groups.  Likewise, I have a User and Group class.  Both the User and Group classes contain a Privileges property in it that's a collection of Privilege objects.

So NHibernate created a Privilege table that contains both a reference to the User and the Group tables.  I'm wondering if there's a way to tell NHibernate to simply create two tables.  One for GroupPrivileges and one for UserPrivileges.

Answer (score 0):

In your collection mapping just fill out the `table` attribute - like this (if you do not - it takes the name from the class' name contained in the collection - which is why nHibernate put both foreign-keys in the same table):

```
<class name="Partner">
   <id name="Id">
     <generator class="native"/>
   </id>
   <bag name="Privileges" table="UserPrivileges" ...>
 </class>
```